# Will increasing physical RAM help in less virtual memory usage and avoid virtual memory bottlenecks in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory, performance-tuning

In Linux, for a 8GB RAM server, when could we say virtual memory is actually used more? I.e., what is the number of page faults which says system is using more virtual memory?

Comment: Memory usage (excluding cache/buffers) will of course be exactly the same, as will [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) usage. Are you perhaps referring to swap?

Answer (score 0):

Of course yes, Virtual Memory (known as Swap in Linux) will be used less when there is enough memory.

There is a kernel parameter called `swappiness` that controls how much swap is likely to be used. Tune it to your needs. To see current value (all commands need root):

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

and to set the value

```
sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

and to persist it, open `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add (or change)

```
vm.swappiness=10
```

More information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness).

Consider value as percent, and less value means using less swap.

On my laptop with 16GB RAM, using 10 I'm just fine.